# How to order django rest framework search results by the query written?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, server

I want to order my django search results (DRF) in the order it was written. For example when I search https://mywebsite.com/api/title=one,two,five,nine so the first result from the API should be Post One, Post Two, Post Five, and Nine and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [OrderingFilter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter), or you can use 3rd party library `django-filter`

Comment: With what logic does the frontend decide the order?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.